# Creating object for Amazon MWS api class not working in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, aws-sdk

I have added amazon MWS API files at webroot folder in cakephp3.And I tried to call that api classes inside my controller. But its not working. It showing following error
Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\MarketplaceWebService_Client' not found

Here is my code within a function

```
require_once 'MarketplaceWebService/Samples/.config.inc.php';
        require_once 'MarketplaceWebService/Model/SubmitFeedRequest.php';
        require_once 'MarketplaceWebService/Client.php';
        require_once 'MarketplaceWebService/Model/GetFeedSubmissionResultRequest.php';
        $accesskey=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
        $secretkey=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
        $serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com";
        $config = array (
          'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
          'ProxyHost' => null,
          'ProxyPort' => -1,
          'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
        );
        $service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client($accesskey,$secretkey,$config,APPLICATION_NAME,APPLICATION_VERSION);
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new MarketplaceWebService_Client` will try to locate that class in your *current* namespace. You presumably want `new \MarketplaceWebService_Client` instead (or something along those lines, depending on whether or not it's defined in a namespace in the implementation).

You probably also want to read up on namespaces, composer and autoloading, as all of your `require_once` calls can probably be eliminated with suitable updates to your environment.